# css every n-th img in new row

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I have a react component and I would like to display inline-block 3 photos in a row with it's names under each photo, and every next 3 elements under (in new row) and so on...

I think I need to use something with`:nth-child(3n+1)` but something goes wrong...

```js
const Photos=(props)=>{
    return(
        <div className="photos-list">
            <img className="photo-img"
                src={props.memoriesPath}
                alt={props.memoriesName}
            />
            <div className="photo-name">{props.memoriesName}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Photos
```

Could you please tell me how should css look like?

Answer (score 0):

wrap all photos components in a div then style div with grid box like this:

```
<div classname="parent">
   <Photos />
   <Photos />
   <Photos />
</div>
```

and css:

```
.parent {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
}
```